# About the 3D UI engine in open-source

Tags: user-interface, open-source, 3d

There are many 3D UI engines in SourceForge and other opensource forum, I would like know which is best one you used?

1. Support D3D in Windows
2. Provide UI Builder tool
3. Support Auto Layout
4. Easy to do localization

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 3d engines or only interfaces? For an interface you could use for example Qt, which supports basic 3d features.

Comment: Yeah I am also confused by the UI part, could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please expand this answer.**

### [CrystalSpace 3D](http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/Main_Page)

*License:* LGPL license
*Language:* C++

CrystalSpace is really full-featured. With 2d and 3d modules, sound modules, physics and collision detection.

### [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/)

*License:* LGPL licence
*Language:* C++
*Platform:* Windows, Linux, Mac OS X

OGRE is a very active framework, but it's not a full-featured framework. You have to find separate sound physic engines. There is support for a lot of advanced features like shaders. A menu module is included too.

### [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/)

*License:* Irrlicht licence (similar to zlib)
*Language:* C++

### [Sauerbraten](http://sauerbraten.org/)

*Licence:* zlib (only the source code, not the media)

### [Quake III Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_3)

*License:* GPL (only source code, not the media)
*3D-driver*: OpenGL

### Others

A lot more can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines).

Comment: Sauerbraten is a nice one, and I absolutely love the in-game level editing, it makes working on levels very easy, for the most part.

Comment: FYI: Quake III is OpenGL, not D3D.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) - it is available under GPL and a commercial license and has canvas type windows for 3d surfaces.

You can use its powerful GUI for tools and embed the 3d view inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a game, this might not be appropriate but you might want to look at WPF.

The latest version supports a certain amount of integration with D3D.

Comment: Not sure this qualifies as open-source.